# Does (A and B) entails (A if and only if B) and what is intuition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is the next statement correct: (A∧B)⊨(A⇔B) ?

Formal definition of entailment is this: α⊨β if and only if, in every model in which α is true, β is also true.

I used a truth table to show that there is only one model {A=True, B=True} where (A∧B)=True. (A⇔B) is also True in this model. It means (A∧B)⊨(A⇔B) is correct.

There exist model2 = {A=False, B=False}, (A⇔B) is True in model2. But (A∧B) is not True in model2.

Can you please provide intuition on what does it mean? Does it extend our knowledge base (A∧B) if we add a new statement (A⇔B)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is correct and you have shown it via truth table. Knowing that $A \land B$ implies that both $A$ and $B$ are true, thus $A \iff B$ follows, i.e. it does not extend our knowledge base if $A \iff B$ is added as a new statement, since we already know both $A$ and $B$ are true.

There is a different way to derive $A\iff B$ from $A\land B$, that is, via natural deduction:

\begin{align}
 1. &\quad A\land B&\text{Premise}\\
 2. &\quad A &\text{Simplification}\\
 3. &\quad B &\text{Simplification}\\
 4. &\quad \neg B \lor A &\text{Conjunction}\\
 5. &\quad \neg A \lor B &\text{Conjunction}\\
 6. &\quad B \implies A &\text{Material Implication}\\
 7. &\quad A \implies B &\text{Material Implication}\\
 8. &\quad A \iff B &\text{Material Equivalence}
\end{align}

or, if your definition of biconditional includes the alternate definition $(A \land B)\lor (\neg A \land \neg B)$ (instead of only the standard $(A \implies B) \land (B \implies A)$), then the conclusion can be drawn from one simple use of the Conjunction rule.

Comment: From $A$ you can just use weakening to infer $B \to A$, no need for the extra steps.

Comment: @DanielV I know that the rule you stated is valid, but I can't find any resources regarding this rule in natural deduction/first order logic. Could you be so kind as to provide a link?

Comment: It is fundamental to natural deduction, I think you need to find a resource on the entire logic.

Comment: @DanielV Is this stub the rule you are referring to? -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonicity_of_entailment

Comment: It is related.  It depends on if you are doing N.D. in Gentzen tree style or Fitch style or Hilbert Style.  One way in Gentzen style is $$\dfrac{A \vdash B}{A,X \vdash B}$$ In Fitch style an instance would look like 
$$\begin{array} {ll}
\quad A & \text{Assumption 1} \\
\quad \quad B & \text{Assumption 2} \\
\quad \quad A & \text{Copy} \\
\quad B \to A & \text{discharge assumption 2} \\
A \to (B \to A) & \text{discharge assumption 1}
\end{array}$$

In Hilbert style, it is just the first axiom schema, sometimes called "K" or "weakening", it is just $$\vdash A \to (B \to A)$$